# Inconsistent Unicode character substitution with WPF

Tags: wpf, unicode

It appears that my WPF app is replacing some Unicode characters with others.

With this simple example:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFUnicodeFail.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFUnicodeFail"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="40">

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label>◀</Label>
    <Label>&#x25C0;</Label>
    <Label>◄</Label>
    <Label>&#x25C4;</Label>
    <Label>▲</Label>
</StackPanel>
```

I get this result:

[image: Result with Segoe UI]

While if I switch the font to Arial, I get this:

[image: Result with Arial]

None of this makes much sense, because the first two labels should be the [BLACK LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE (U+25C0) ◀](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25c0/index.htm) and the following two should be [BLACK LEFT-POINTING POINTER (U+25C4) ◄](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25c4/index.htm). The TRIANGLE is supposed to be an equilateral triangle, while the POINTER is supposed to be flatter. With Segoe UI, the TRIANGLE is transparently replaced with the POINTER. With Arial, it's even worse, they are switched.

Trying both including the character itself in the source code and the `&#x` code yields the same result as seen in the images above.

In Word 2016, I try the three different characters with Segoe UI and I get the correct result (although with inconsistent scaling even though the font size is the same, but that's a different issue):

[image: Result with Segoe UI in Word 2016]

Why does this happen? How do I get consistent results with different fonts? Or at least, how do I get the TRIANGLE with Segoe UI and other fonts that seem to change it to the POINTER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the fonts you're using with the Windows Character Map (**Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Character Map**), you'll notice that the *Segoe UI* font is missing the `U+25C0` character, so does the *Arial* too. I suppose, this is implementation specific how does the system treat such a case when a character has to be displayed that is missing in the font. If you choose the *Segoe UI Symbol* font, you can see those characters correctly displayed by a WPF app. Maybe MS Word can do this automatically?

If you want to ensure that all your symbols will be correctly displayed in different fonts, you should probably check those fonts with the Character Map tool.